# Missing variable in R mixed ANOVA output

Tags: r, model, anova, mixed

[This is a preview of my data. I have 2 conditions (1, 2) and two repeated measures time intervals (stress.pre, stress.post)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08SE0.png)

```
> head(data_long_new)
  participant.number condition       time subjective.stress
1                  1         1 stress.pre                 1
2                  2         1 stress.pre                 2
3                  3         1 stress.pre                 1
4                  4         1 stress.pre                 1
5                  5         1 stress.pre                 3
6                  6         1 stress.pre                 1
```

I am trying to run a One Between Subject Variable, One Within Subject Variable ANOVA with the following code:

```
model2 <- aov(subjective.stress ~ (condition*time) + 
Error(participant.number/(condition)), data = data_long_new)
summary(model2)
```

I get the following output from R, but my 'Time' variable is not there...

```
Error: participant.number
      Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
condition  1   0.08  0.0833   0.045  0.833
Residuals 73 135.09  1.8505               

Error: Within
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
time            1   1.93   1.927   3.963 0.05025 . 
condition:time  1   4.08   4.083   8.399 0.00495 **
Residuals      73  35.49   0.486                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Any idea how to get time included in the output? Cheers!

Comment: Add a sample of your data.frame, not an image please.

Comment: @Terru_theTerror I have added a sample

Comment: If I create a dataset `df1 <- data.frame(participant.number = 1:100, 
     condition = rep(1:4, each = 25), 
     time = sample(c("stress.pre", "stress.post"), 100, replace = TRUE),
     subjective.stress = sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE))` Not getting an error with `aov(subjective.stress ~ (condition*time) , data = df1)`

Comment: thanks @akrun, im mostly wondering where 'Time' has gone in my output, as it only seems to show Condition and Residuals... any idea?

Comment: You may need to check the `str(yourdata)` or `colnames(yourdata)` for any whitespace in the column names

Comment: i ran colnames(mydata) and there is a bit of a gap between 'condition' and 'time', my apologies, i'm not so familiar with this issue, why is this, what can I do to fix this? @akrun

Comment: @akrun You can update your column names with `trimws(colnames(yourdata))`